# Troubles with running Selenium with ChromeDriver without having the Chrome browser installed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would want to scrap the webside and i decided to use Selenium for taking loaded content with an AJAX call via javascript.

So, i try to run Selenium with ChromeDriver - on Windows computer without having the Chrome browser app. I try to do it two way but it works.

#### Using the saved exe to the project

*Code:*

```py
from selenium import webdriver
 
chromedriver_bin = './materials/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
 
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--headless')
# option.binary_location = chromedriver_bin --> tried with and without it
 
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=chromedriver_bin)
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=option)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

*Error:*

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "C:\Users\...\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00ACA813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x00A5C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00965358]
        (No symbol) [0x00981A9E]
        (No symbol) [0x00980579]
        (No symbol) [0x009B0C55]
        (No symbol) [0x009B093C]
        (No symbol) [0x009AA536]
        (No symbol) [0x009882DC]
        (No symbol) [0x009893DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D2AABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D6A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D6456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B551E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x00A65F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00A62328]
        (No symbol) [0x00A6240B]
        (No symbol) [0x00A54FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7755343D+18]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77BD9812+99]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77BD97E5+54]
```

*The binary exe is working by this path:*

```bash
$ ./materials/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping
ChromeDriver safe.
[1702553766.704][SEVERE]: Check failed: false.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

#### By webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install()

*Code:*

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--headless')

service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=option)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

*Error:*

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "C:\Users\...\.venv\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 64, in get_latest_release_version
    determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
(.venv)
```

What's wrong i'm doing? Maybe, there are other ways to solve my problem.

Thx, all for answerings!

Comment: All Selenium does is automate browser tasks. How are you supposed to do that if you don't have the browser? The way to solve your problem is to install the browser.

Comment: @OysterShucker, i see now. There is just IE on computer. I don't have an opportunity to install Chrome. Im trying to run it with IE but have a new error:

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. CreateProcess() failed for edge with the following command: msedge.exe --ie-mode-force --internet-explorer-integration=iemode --user-data-dir=C:\Users\HRISTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IEDriver-b771173b-9554-4626-bc98-e49af7ae02bf --no-first-run --no-service-autorun --disable-sync --disable-features=msImplicitSignin --disable-popup-blocking --enable-features=msIEModeAlwaysWaitForUnload http://localhost:62218/

Comment: what OS/version are you running?